# Even after setting the log level my logs are printed twice in the logfile. Need what to be fixed here

Tags: python, logging

```
logger.py
=========
import logging

level = logging.INFO
filename = "xyz.txt"
class printlog():
    #def __init__(self):

    @staticmethod
    def debug(msg):
        print("In Debug")
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(level)
        handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.debug(msg)

    @staticmethod
    def info(msg):
        print("In Debug")
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(level)
        handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.info(msg)

    @staticmethod
    def warning(msg):
        print("In Warning")
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(level)
        handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.warning(msg)
    @staticmethod
    def error(msg):
        print("In Error")
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(level)
        handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        logger.error(msg)       


_____________________________
====
main.py
=======
from test1 import printlog


plog = printlog()
plog.debug('Hello debug')
plog.info('hello info')
plog.error('hello error')
plog.warning('hello warning')
--------------------

When I run main.py I get the below output. The solution required for me is that it should print messages only once(1). Whereas in the below output, it prints multiple times. Please help.
```

> 2018-01-10 11:42:48,961 - test1 - INFO - hello info
>   2018-01-10 11:42:48,961 - test1 - INFO - hello info
>   2018-01-10 11:42:48,961 - test1 - ERROR - hello error
>   2018-01-10 11:42:48,961 - test1 - ERROR - hello error
>   2018-01-10 11:42:48,961 - test1 - ERROR - hello error
>   2018-01-10 11:42:48,961 - test1 - WARNING - hello warning
>   2018-01-10 11:42:48,961 - test1 - WARNING - hello warning
>   2018-01-10 11:42:48,961 - test1 - WARNING - hello warning
>   2018-01-10 11:42:48,961 - test1 - WARNING - hello warning

Comment: When you add two handlers, then each entry will be "handled" twice.

Comment: Are you referring to the handler & logger, as the 2 handlers? How can I resolve it . Pls help

Comment: Each of your methods creates and installs a new handler on _every_ invocation. Fix that by not doing it.

Comment: Should I be putting the handlers in def __init__(self): method??

Comment: Can you just give an example of what needs to be updated pls